# Can we set the port number for listening in some automatic way rather than hardcoding it?

Tags: linux, sockets, port

In typical example client server programs found on the net, we can see the following hardcoded way of specifying the port number which is actually the process id of the process which will be used to handle the incomming messages.

Can we set the port number for listening in some automatic way rather than hardcoding it?
***I mean how are we always supposed to the know the port number beforehand?***

```
  serverAddr.sin_family         = AF_INET;
  /* Set port number, using htons function to use proper byte order 
     Port number is the process id of the process which will be used to
     handle the incomming messages.
  */
  serverAddr.sin_port           = htons (7891);
  /* Set IP address to localhost */
  serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr    = inet_addr ("127.0.0.1");
  /* Set all bits of the padding field to 0 */
  memset(serverAddr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof serverAddr.sin_zero);  

  /*---- Bind the address struct to the socket ----*/
  bind(welcomeSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
```

Comment: How are you supposed to connect to a service of you *don't* know the port beforehand?!

Comment: @Biffen But port number is the process id, so are we supposed to "guess" the process id?

Comment: What?! What do you mean by ‘*port number is the process id*’? Where did you get that?

Comment: @Biffen http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/definition/port-number == `A port number is a way to identify a specific process to which an Internet or other network message is to be forwarded when it arrives at a server.` So, I thought it must be the process id then.

Comment: @Biffen in the OP's question text he states that - `Port number is the process id of the process which will be used to
     handle the incomming messages`

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius The port number is NOT a process ID, unless you have a specific case/reason to make a system to behave like that !

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius That does *not* say that the port number *is the same as* the process ID, it just says that the former are mapped to the latter.

Comment: @deimus I can see that, but that doesn't make it make more sense.

Comment: @Biffen From the first look agree makes no sense, but there might be a technical reason, why he wants to achieve such a communication mechanism

Comment: Have you considered specifying it in a configuration file?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams my understanding was wrong regarding the meaning of port number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the port number is dynamically identified during the execution process of the client, then transfer it to server via another interprocess communication. e.g.

I would suggest to perform following :

1. Establish initial connection with defined and hardcoded port number()
2. Transfer the port/process id of the client to server
3. Close the initial connection
4. Establish the wanted connection

Answer (score 2):

In a typical server application, the port is often hardcoded, or at least a *default* is hardcoded because port numbers are normally "well-known". It's how you tell the server what application layer protocol (and finally, what socket) you're trying to talk to. That's (normally) the correct thing to do.
For example, you know that a web server (HTTP) usually runs on port 80 and HTTP over TLS runs on 443. There is a list of assigned numbers for that. This port is what the client normally expects, and this is the port the client will normally, by default, try to talk to -- unless you do a special dance. By default, this will "just work".

Of course it is entirely possible to run the same service on a different port (say, 88 or 8080, to stick with the HTTP example), but then the client has to know this, and unless the client has been redirected in some way, the user will have to manually enter the port number. This is tedious because things no longer "just work".
It gets particularly annoying in some cases where deliberately wrong port numbers are used for "security" (for example DSM's new security advisor raises a warning if you run SSH on its standard port... which is a real "WTF?!" because a different port offers zero added security but makes logging in legitimately a nuisance, you need to remember adding the port number every time).

Still, because sometimes people want to (or *need to*, for example if a given port is blocked on the gateway, or if a port is already taken by another service) run a service on a non-standard port. Therefore, it is usually possible to specify an alternate port either one the command line (via `argc/argv`) or in a config file. Thus, if you just run `server`, you might have it listen on 1234, which is the default that you hardcoded, but if you run `server -p 7890` it will listen on port 7890 instead.